# How to get the element my cursor positioned over when a window.scroll event occurs?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

```html
<div id="div1">d1</div>
<div id="div2">d2</div>
<div id="div3">d3</div>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  console.log(e.target);
})

window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target);
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 12px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

In the above code, when I trigger the scroll event when my cursor is over a div, event target always is the HTML document. I want to get the target element like the click event's target. It is for implementing a feature for triggering a scroll animation only when the cursor is over a div that I created for this purpose.

Comment: Just add the event to the div which you would like to hover. Did you tried that?

Comment: @LarsFlieger yes `div1.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  console.log(e.target)
})` It didn't work. I am not sure how scroll event works, but I believe it is because it won't trigger when the element is not scrollable?

Comment: `scroll` is not an event on `window`, scrolling on `document` fires the event.

Comment: @Teemu the scroll event on documents does bubble, listening on `window` is just fine

Comment: @Kaiido Yep, but there doesn't seem to be phases to capture downwards ..?

Comment: @Teemu well yes, from the window in capturing to the document in at_target and back to the window in bubbling.

Comment: @Kaiido Right, the div OP wants is not on the way.

Comment: No, the div doesn't scroll, so it won't be in the event path. But listening for this event on the `window` object is fine (listening for the scroll on an other element wouldn't bubble though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `:hover` selector to get all the elements that are currently being hovered. If you are only interested in a few of these then you can filter out this list (which will also contain the `<body>` and `<html>` elements) by using an other selector, like a specific class.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
  document.querySelector(".hovered")?.classList.remove("hovered");
  document.querySelector(".target:hover")?.classList.add("hovered");
})
```

```css
div.target {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 12px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.target.hovered {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="target" id="div1">d1</div>
<div class="target" id="div2">d2</div>
<div class="target" id="div3">d3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets the job done.

Comment: @Kaiido Add a check that `querySelector(".target:hover")` isn't null. (Causes error when hovering at certain points)

Comment: @LarsFlieger it's already handled by `?.` `document.querySelector(".hovered")?.classList`

Comment: @Kaiido Now yes. :)

Comment: It's there since yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Since your feature relies on a mouse hover and not any other devices, maybe you could use the `wheel` event instead of `scroll` ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this event, but I need to implement this feature for mobile as well. Maybe I could handle it with `touchstart` and `touchmove` etc, but Kaiido's answer is more abstract in this case. Thanks for the answer :)